# Why python object is not iterateable

Tags: python, arrays, iteration

I am getting following response from an http post. I extract the data as follows.

`sch = request.forms.get('schedule')`

```
sch = {0=[0, 0.00, 5.59, 8.00, 14.59, 17.00, 0.59], 1=[1, 1.00, 0.59], 2=[2, 1.00, 0.59], 3=[3, 1.00, 5.59, 8.00, 0.59], 4=[4, 1.00, 12.59, 15.00, 0.59], 5=[5, 1.00, 2.59, 5.00, 14.59, 17.00, 0.59], 6=[6, 1.00, 23.59]}
```

I am only interesting in values. I know the object is not a exactly a dict.

I have tried following without any luck.

```
for k,v in sch:
   print v
```

what I am expecting back is

> [0, 0.00, 5.59, 8.00, 14.59, 17.00, 0.59]
>      [1, 1.00, 0.59]

and so on.

I have even tried converting it to a list object.`list(sch)` Still I cannot get desired results. Obviously `shc.get[0]` didn't work either.

I think problem can be solved with and map function, but don't exactly how.

Comment: the object is not exactly a dict. but heres a question for you. what IS it? (and what it looks like is a different question. what is the actual type of the response?)

Comment: replace `=` with `:`.

Comment: What kind of response does the remote server send? Probably there is a parser written for its schema. At any rate, clarify the steps you take when processing the response. It looks kind of urlform encoded, which you should be able to work with

Comment: @DirtyBit I cannot change = its not in my hand. I get the response as shown above

Comment: @ParitoshSingh this is the actual response. Sorry comment object is not actually a dict. I is judgment

Comment: @humble_pie: That is not the actual response, since that would not be valid Python code. Do you get this as a string? Is it an object whose representation looks like this?

Comment: @humble_pie still doesn't quite answer it. Find out more about the response. what is the datatype? is it a string? check these things, inspect the response, see what you can figure out about it.

Comment: Yes the response is String type. sch = request.forms.get('schedule')

Comment: @ParitoshSingh I have updated the question, explaining how I get the response

Comment: @humble_pie, see if the answer posted below helps? You may accept it if it does. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Not quiet sure about the type of response, but if you want to get the values list, probably convert the response to `str`, replace the `=` with `:` and convert it back to `dict` that you can iterate over:

```
import ast
sch = "{
         0=[0, 0.00, 5.59, 8.00, 14.59, 17.00, 0.59], 1=[1, 1.00, 0.59], 
         2=[2, 1.00, 0.59], 3=[3, 1.00, 5.59, 8.00, 0.59], 
         4=[4, 1.00, 12.59, 15.00, 0.59], 
         5=[5, 1.00, 2.59, 5.00, 14.59, 17.00, 0.59], 6=[6, 1.00, 23.59]
       }"

sch = ast.literal_eval(sch.replace("=",":"))

for k,v in sch.items():
    print(v)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[0, 0.0, 5.59, 8.0, 14.59, 17.0, 0.59]
[1, 1.0, 0.59]
[2, 1.0, 0.59]
[3, 1.0, 5.59, 8.0, 0.59]
[4, 1.0, 12.59, 15.0, 0.59]
[5, 1.0, 2.59, 5.0, 14.59, 17.0, 0.59]
[6, 1.0, 23.59]
```

Answer (score 0):

When defining a dictionary you should us : not =. So the Dictionary should look like this.

```py
sch = {0: [0, 0.00, 5.59, 8.00, 14.59, 17.00, 0.59], 1: [1, 1.00, 0.59], 2: [2, 1.00, 0.59], 3: [3, 1.00, 5.59, 8.00, 0.59], 4: [4, 1.00, 12.59, 15.00, 0.59], 5: [5, 1.00, 2.59, 5.00, 14.59, 17.00, 0.59], 6: [6, 1.00, 23.59]}
```

And when you are getting the keys and values you should use the .items() function like this:

```py
for k, v in sch.items():
   print v
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[0, 0.0, 5.59, 8.0, 14.59, 17.0, 0.59]
[1, 1.0, 0.59]
[2, 1.0, 0.59]
[3, 1.0, 5.59, 8.0, 0.59]
[4, 1.0, 12.59, 15.0, 0.59]
[5, 1.0, 2.59, 5.0, 14.59, 17.0, 0.59]
[6, 1.0, 23.59]
```

Comment: Uh, nope. You should read the question and the following comments on it again.